# Compute average of numbers in a text file in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Lets say I have a file with each line representing a number. How do I find average of all the numbers in the file in Scala - Spark.

```
val data = sc.textFile("../../numbers.txt")
val sum = data.reduce( (x,y) => x+y )
val avg = sum/data.count()
```

The problem here is x and y are strings. How do I convert them into Long within the reduce function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to apply a [`RDD.map`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) which parses the strings before reducing them:

```
val sum = data.map(_.toInt).reduce(_+_)
val avg = sum / data.count()
```

But I think you're better off using [`DoubleRDDFunctions.mean`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions) instead of calculating it yourself:

```
val mean = data.map(_.toInt).mean()
```